# Oracle executeUpdate() not responding in Java Servlet

Tags: java, oracle, servlets, execute

I have two nearly identical codes that Updates multiple jpg file as blob into tables.
Mysteriously..
One works. The other doesn't work.
The one that does not work not just don't work but also Oracle DB does not respond to Apache Web Server.(Or at least it seems like so.)

Here is the working code.
It receives 120+ jpg files from jsp input tag and sends to this servlet.
And it does it's job perfectly.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    
    try {
        //connection
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "KSJ", 
        "1234");
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        
        response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        int categoryID = 13;
        int productID = categoryID*10000;

        int jpgIndex = 1;
        int itemIndex = 1;
        int executeResult = 0;
        boolean isExcuted = true;
        

        String sql = "UPDATE PRODETAIL_T SET PDTT_MAINPIC = ?, PDTT_SMALLPIC1 = ?, PDTT_SMALLPIC2 = 
        ?, PDTT_SMALLPIC3 = ?, PDTT_SMALLPIC4 = ?, PDTT_SMALLPIC5 = ? "
                   + "WHERE PDTT_PDTID = '";
        String[] sqlArr = new String[20];
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        
        //looping jpg files
        System.out.println("request size : "+request.getParts().size());
        for(Part jpg : request.getParts()) {
            if(isExcuted) {
                productID++;
                sqlArr[itemIndex-1] = sql;
                sqlArr[itemIndex-1] += productID + "' AND PDTT_PDTCGTID = " + categoryID;
                pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sqlArr[itemIndex-1]);
                isExcuted = false;
                jpgIndex = 1;
            }
            pstmt.setBinaryStream(jpgIndex, jpg.getInputStream(), (int)jpg.getSize());
            jpgIndex++;
            
            if((jpgIndex-1)%6 == 0) {
                System.out.println(sqlArr[itemIndex-1]);
              executeResult = pstmt.executeUpdate();
              pstmt.close();
              isExcuted = true;
              itemIndex++;
              if(executeResult ==0) {System.out.println("jpg upload error");}
              executeResult = 0;
            }
            if(itemIndex == 21) {
                System.out.println("commit bulk image successful for category"+categoryID);
                con.commit();
                break;
            }
        }
        con.close();
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    doGet(request, response);
}
```

Now the nearly identical code that does not work

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws 
ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", 
            "KSJ", "1234");
            con.setAutoCommit(false);

            response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
            PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
            String sqlTemplate = "UPDATE REVIEW_T SET RVT_PICTURE1= ?, RVT_PICTURE2= ?, RVT_PICTURE3= 
            ? WHERE RVT_THUMBSUP =";
            String sql;

            int rowNum = 1;
            int jpgIndex = 1;
            int executeResult = 0;
            boolean isExcuted = true;
            
            for(Part jpg : request.getParts()) {
                if(isExcuted) {
                    sql = sqlTemplate + rowNum;
                    System.out.println(sql);
                    pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                    isExcuted = false;
                    jpgIndex = 1;
                }
                pstmt.setBinaryStream(jpgIndex, jpg.getInputStream(), (int)jpg.getSize());
                jpgIndex++;
                if((jpgIndex-1)%3==0) {
 works upto here>>  rowNum = rowNum + 1;
    Error here >>   executeResult = pstmt.executeUpdate();
                    if(executeResult == 1) {
                        System.out.println("One upload successful");
                    }
                    pstmt.close();
                    isExcuted = true;
                    if(executeResult ==0) {System.out.println("jpg upload error");}
                    executeResult = 0;
                }
                if(rowNum == 101) {
                    System.out.println("commit bulk image successful");
                    con.commit();
                    break;
                }
            }
            con.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    doGet(request, response);
}
```

I investigated all through with sysout, and the code hangs exactly at

```
executeResult = pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Eventually Eclipse/Apache will throw some error saying code is still executing and cause memory leak.
I manually inserted into the blob columns like this in SQL developer

```
UPDATE RVT SET RVT_PICTURE1 = '1' , RVT_PICTURE2 = '1' ,RVT_PICTURE3 = '1'   WHERE RVT_THUMBSUP = 2;
```

And it works no problem so I don't think there is a problem in the table.
Also I could update at least one row sometimes. (But not now after I changed code number of times.)

This is the error code from Apache/Eclipse coming after dozens of seconds.

```
WARNING: The web application [ElecMarket1.0] is still processing a request 
that has yet to finish. This is very likely to create a memory leak. You can 
control the time allowed for requests to finish by using the unloadDelay 
attribute of the standard Context implementation. Stack trace of request 
processing thread:[
```

Comment: I am sorry for the long codes my apologies. It actually works now. SURPRISINGLY I didn't do anything and it starts to work after 2 hours of this and that. I throughly checked there is no wrong in my code and I didn't change anything and all of sudden it worked and I updated 1800+ images in one shot.(After I checked it works I changed if(rowNum == 101) to if(rowNum==651) to get all 650x3 images updated.

Comment: My problem is that this error happened and now it doesn't happen with me contributed nothing. I even restarted eclipse and PC hour ago and it didn't work. Now it does as if God's mercy happened. My  system is Ryzen 5 3500X with 32G RAM. Oracle 11g with Apache Tomcat 9.0. How can I explain this mystery?

Comment: I just ran the Update query again to excute 650 update queries to update 1950 jpg files it worked again. More over it worked much faster this time. First one took very long almost 15seconds (I didn't measure. just feeling). Second one took only less than 5 seconds.

Comment: When it happens, check v$active_session_history (if you're licensed for it) and you can see where the time is lost for that session. That gives an indicator as to where to pursue options